# (Racket) "Cannot reference an identifier before its definition" with identifier imported from module

Tags: module, racket

I have a file "exceptions.rkt"

```
#lang racket
(module exceptions racket
  (provide Macro/Raise Macro/Assert Macro/Assert* Macro/Domain-Assert)

; ... Definitions for provided symbols...

) ; End of module, end of file
```

`Macro/Raise` etc are not actually macros defined with define-syntax, they're just unary functions generated with `syntax-rules` and assigned a name

```
(define Macro/Raise
  (syntax-rules ()
; ... body not important ...
))
```

and in the same folder as "exceptions.rkt", I have a file "tables.rkt".

```
#lang racket
(module tables racket
    (require "exceptions.rkt")
    (define-syntax Assert Macro/Assert)

; ... more stuff...

) ; End of module, end of file
```

but this results in `Macro/Assert: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition in module: 'tables phase: 1`

I've tried reading the doc and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In order for definitions to be usable during the macro definition phase, use `for-syntax`:

```
(require (for-syntax "exceptions.rkt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't need the `(module exceptions racket ...)` wrapper over the code since `#lang racket` already generates a module.